# SQLITE datetime for different timzone required, not only localtime

Tags: sqlite, datetime, timezone

I want to fetch date and time, in different timezone using SQLITE. Say, I get the value as, 20160118T010856 in input, but I require it to change to Australian, England and other timezone.

What I am currently able to do is :

```
 select datetime('2016-01-18T04:13:39','localtime');
```

Which only provides me for my current local time. Kindly help.

Comment: So you want to add a certain offset to a timestamp?

Comment: @ketan In nutshell I want an input time to be changed to all the other timezones. I checked http://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/functions/datetime.php, seems its not possible in sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible in sqlite. Your best bet is to store the datetime as UTC and do the conversion outside the database.

From the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) you could apply an offset(modifier) to a date and time, but it doesn't take Daylight Savings Time into account.